# Database onUpgrade method is never called

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm trying to upgrade my database from version 1 to version 2. I'm assigning `DATABASE_VERSION = 2` (first version was assigned too) but `onUpgrade` never called.
May be there is an obvious mistake in the code, but I can't see it beacause I'm trying to solve this problem for a long time.

Here is the code of database helper class:

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;
    public static String DB_PATH;
    public static String DB_NAME = "db.sqlite3";
    public SQLiteDatabase database;
    public final Context context;

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        this.context = context;

        File direct = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                + "/.test");
        if (!direct.exists()) {
            if (direct.mkdir())
                ;
        }
        DB_PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()
                + "/.test/";
    }

    public void createDataBase() {
        boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();
        if (!dbExist) {
            try {
                copyDataBase();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(this.getClass().toString(), "Copying error");
                throw new Error("Error copying database!");
            }
        }
    }

    private boolean checkDataBase() {
        SQLiteDatabase checkDb = null;
        try {
            String path = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
            checkDb = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(path, null,
                    SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            Log.e(this.getClass().toString(), "Error while checking db");
        }
        if (checkDb != null) {
            checkDb.close();
        }
        return checkDb != null;
    }

    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {
        InputStream externalDbStream = context.getAssets().open(
                "databases/" + DB_NAME);
        String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        OutputStream localDbStream = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int bytesRead;
        while ((bytesRead = externalDbStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            localDbStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
        localDbStream.close();
        externalDbStream.close();
    }

    public SQLiteDatabase openDataBase() throws SQLException {
        String path = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        if (database == null) {
            createDataBase();
            database = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(path, null,
                    SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
        }
        return database;
    }

    // some unimportant methods

@Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        Log.w("myLogs", " --- onUpgrade database --- ");
    }
```

In Activity I call database like this:

```
DatabaseHelper dbOpenHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
SQLiteDatabase database = dbOpenHelper.openDataBase();
```

Where is my mistake?
Help, please.

**UPD:** `database.getVersion()` returns 0

---

Updated `openDataBase()` method (it's working):

```
public SQLiteDatabase openDataBase() throws SQLException {
    String path = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    if (database == null) {
        createDataBase();
        database = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(path, null,
            SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
        this.getWritableDatabase();
    }
    return database;
}
```

Comment: @Hitman47 Edited question. Please, look.

Comment: What is the result of invoking `database.getVersion()` after opening database?

Comment: @Hitman47 It seems to me, that you are not competent in this question, if you are asking such things.

Comment: @Andremoniy updated question. It always returns 0.

Comment: @Hitman47 you don't need to call `onUpgrade(..)`. It's called automaticaly if db version is higher than current.

Comment: @Sabre, this means that you have never assigned even "1" version to the database. Have you ever changed `DB_NAME` value?

Comment: @Andremoniy No, I'll try to change it and 1) assign version 1 and 2) try to assign v2.

Comment: @Andremoniy tried to rename db, but I got version 0 again.

Comment: @Sabre, no, no no! You don't need to change your DBNAME, it should be always the same, when your change its version

Comment: @Andremoniy I know but I tried to make if I opened app the first time.

Comment: solved my prob. too..

Comment: @Sabre Sometimes I get Nosuchtablefound exception and when I pull the DB I saw db is present but there is no table in that DB. I am using the same approach of copying it from assets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Local database version will always be 0 and `onUpgrade` will not be called, because you never called `getWritableDatabase/getReadableDatabase`, which will bump version and return local db.

So you need:

1. make call `getReadableDatabase();` in your contructor/oncreate, just to trigger process, in case db version is changed
   or
2. manually check sdcard version, `db.getVersion();` compare to current version - `DATABASE_VERSION`. And do what ever you need to do - upgrade or downgrade.

Comment: 1) I tried to call `getWritableDatabase/getReadableDatabase` in constructor and in `openDataBase()` but I always get 0. 2) When I check version I get 0, so if I call `onUpgrade` manually (it's designed to be called automatically) it will be called everytime when database is opened.

Comment: Which database version you check? the one that is on sdcard: openDataBase().getVersion(); or local getWritableDatabase().getVersion()? Can you please check both?

Comment: You're right: `getWritableDatabase().getVersion()` returns 1, `openDataBase().getVersion()` returns 0.

Comment: Btw, why you need onUpgrade? Just to copy a new DB from assets or something else?

Comment: Also, your answer is the best. I needed only to call `getWritableDatabase` in `openDataBase()`